# Compilo uma package e dá erros. A localização do erro está errada

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Após compilar uma package, vem essa mensagem de erro:

> 249/36   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TS_ODO" when expecting one
>   of the following:       := . ( @ % ;  The symbol ":=" was substituted
>   for "TS_ODO" to continue.
>
> 250/34   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DATE" when expecting one
>   of the following:       := . ( @ % ;  The symbol ":=" was substituted
>   for "DATE" to continue.
>
> 274/89   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of
>   the following:       ) , * & = - + < / > at in é mod lembrete not rem
>   =>      <> ou != ou ~= >= <= <> e ou como like2     like4 likec entre || multiset membro submultiset  The symbol ")" was
>   substituted for ";" to continue.

O que passa é que essas Linhas/Colunas que são mostradas, são comentários. Não vi nada, próximo a essas linhas que pudessem me dar uma pista(erros de sintaxe e etc...)

Comment: Descobri o erro e não tem nada a ver com a linha/coluna exibida. O que passa é que declarei algumas variáveis e depois percebi que estavam fora da cláusula `is`. Isso resolveu dois erros e agora falta o terceiro, mas já sei que foram causados pela minha alteração.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. Estava montando uma data, somando um valor a ela para incrementar dias e isso estava errado. O que estava passando que esse problema estava na linha 378 e o erro estava dando na linha 249, 250 e 274. Mas já resolvi.